# Шрифты в tkinter

Tags: python, шрифты, tkinter

Есть ли возможность подгрузить шрифт из файла .ttf ?

Comment: А причём здесь tkinter? Какие шрифты доступны, те и можно выбирать. Если X-server, то ttf там уже давно можно использовать.

Comment: Вся соль , что шрифт нужно загрузить из файла , то есть в системе его может и не быть.

Comment: Для винды есть некоторый хак, описанный [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993290/truly-custom-font-in-tkinter). Но по сути, здесь шрифт ttf устанавливают на лету в систему, после чего вы штатным образом прописываете его в приложение tk. Нативно же для tk прописать работу с шрифтами из файла недоступно - таких методов просто нет для основной реализации tcl/tk

Comment: Вам достаточно будет лишь установить шрифт в системе windows, и всё заработает.